# using 'v-for' to output object to list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have an object that get dynamically updated with various key/value, for the most part it will look like below:

```
object: {
    parentKey1:{
        childKey1:'value', 
        childKey2:'value'
        },
    parentKey2:{
        childKey3:'value', 
        childKey4:'value'
        }
    }
```

I am then using 'v-for' in a list to export the object, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(value, key) in object">{{ key }} - {{ value }}</li>
</ul>
```

Now, it's displaying on the DOM generally how I want it, except that its printing out {} curly brackets around the values.

```
PARENT - { "CHILD": "VALUE" }
```

I'd like it to be:

```
PARENT - CHILD VALUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    object: {
      parentKey1: {
        childKey1: 'value',
        childKey2: 'value'
      },
      parentKey2: {
        childKey3: 'value',
        childKey4: 'value'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in object">
    {{key}} -
    <span v-for="(cvalue, ckey) in value">
         {{ ckey }}  {{ cvalue }} {{' '}}
    <span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a new nested iteration to do that.

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="(parentValue, parentKey) in object">
      <template v-for((childValue, childKey) in parentValue)>
        {{ parentKey }} - {{ childKey }} {{ childValue }}
      </template>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well the value is still an Array thats why it is displayed like that.

Maybe try

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(value, key) in object">{{ key }} - <span v-for="val in value">{{ val }}</span></li>
</ul>
```